# Any mouse movement pattern recognizer for Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need some kind of mouse movement pattern recognizer for Cocoa. What I specifically need is to recognize a mouse "shake" or some kind of circular movement. I've read about [Protractor](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36269.pdf) but I would like to know if there is some kind of library already implemented.

I'm currently setting a global event monitor to track mouse movements system wide but I need to be able to recognize specific patterns like circular movement, shake, and similar ones.

```
_eventMonitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSMouseMovedMask handler:^(NSEvent *eventoEntrada) {
    NSLog(@"Movement detected");

    NSPoint loc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
    NSLog(@"x:%.2f y:%.2f",loc.x, loc.y);
}];
```

Is there any library out there to achieve this task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Quartz library in mac OS X 
1- define the mouse event mask in your applicationDidFinishLaunching method like that

```
CFMachPortRef      mouseEventTap;
CGEventMask        mouseEventMask;


CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopMouseSource;



// Create an event tap. We are interested in key presses.

mouseEventMask = (1 << kCGEventMouseMoved) ;

mouseEventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGTailAppendEventTap, 0,
                                 mouseEventMask, mouseCGEventCallback, NULL);



if (!mouseEventTap) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create event tap\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Create a run loop source.
runLoopMouseSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(
                                              kCFAllocatorDefault, mouseEventTap, 0);



// Add to the current run loop.

CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopMouseSource,
                   kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

// Enable the event tap.
 CGEventTapEnable(mouseEventTap, true);
```

Then implement the call back function mouseCGEventCallback  like this

```
    CGEventRef mouseCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type,
                         CGEventRef event, void *refcon)
   {


    if (type == kCGEventMouseMoved)
    {
       //here you can detect any information you need from the event field key


       return event;
    }

 }
```

For more information about the event field check this

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventField

Hope to be helpful for you